# Getting correct environment variables

Tags: linux, shell, go, environment-variables

I'm writing a go utility that needs to use the command `which` to get info about if a program is in $PATH or not, but i noticed that while my program works if launched from a terminal, it doesn't work if opened with a double click.

The code that i'm using for that is super simple:

```golang
wichJavaOutput, err := Command("which", "java").CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    return err.Error(), err
}
```

The problem is that this works only partially, if java is installed via a package manager and it's in a common folder it can easily find it, but it java is installed manually and added to `~/.bashrc` or `~./profile` it doesn't work.

I did a pair of test by getting `$PATH` with `os.Getenv` and apparently...
if i launch the program by a terminal the `$PATH` contains the parts from `~/.bashrc` and `~./profile` too, but if i launch it by double clicking it finds all the parts of the `$PATH` except the one in those two files, this kinda make sense considering it's probably the shell loading `~/.bashrc` and `~./profile`, so i tought trying to do `/bin/sh -c which java` or `/bin/bash -c which java` could work but that didn't work either, so here comes the question:

How can i get an environment variable in GO and have the correct one that i would have in terminal?

Comment: Some variation on Command("source ./bashrc && which", "java") or put the environment setup in a script called something like which.sh and have the script set up the environment and then call "which".

Comment: @NicholasRees had to edit it a bit, i'm now using exec.Command("bash", "-c", "source ~/.bashrc ; which java") and... it works, thanks!

Comment: Good deal. Glad that worked.  Now I don’t have to fire up my golang environment to figure out the syntax myself. ;)

Comment: Also, see below comments about making it more portable than just your personal shell and setup. Not clear if you’re doing it for more than just you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is because generally when a program is run by double-clicking on it in a GUI, the `PATH` environment variable is set to a default value.  However, when your program is run in a terminal, it inherits the `PATH` value from the terminal.

The thing to do here is to always use `PATH` and to let the user configure their GUI session appropriately if they want different behavior.  People set different `PATH` values all the time, sometimes just by changing directories, and you cannot know what the user wants it to be guessing from the user's shell configuration.

Moreover, even if you wanted to invoke the user's shell, it isn't always bash (I use zsh) and it isn't always a POSIX-compliant shell (e.g., `tcsh`, `fish`, and others), so there is no set of commands you can invoke the program in `SHELL` with that will always produce a correct result.

If your program really needs to be run from a terminal, then you should ship a `.desktop` file that indicates it should be run from a terminal, and then one will be spawned.  Otherwise, either specify a command-line option that lets the user override the search, or just use `PATH` like other programs do.

Comment: It makes sense.
For now I've sort of found a way to have some sort of configuration that allow for a fallback when `which` doesn't work to avoid using $PATH, so thanks for the tip!
I'm accepting your answer for now, might change later in case someone comes out with a magic way of finding the same $PATH of the terminal despite the possible different shells (but as you made me notice, that seems very unlikely...)